# Remote function for validation

Tags: jquery

I keep getting an undefined for the val that gets passed and not sure why when there's something being put for the form field.

```
$('#addNewUserForm input[name="username"]').rules('add', {
    remote: {
        type: 'post',
        url: 'addnewuser/is_username_available',
        data: {
            'username': function() { return $('#username').val(); }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }
});
```

Comment: does your input with name `username` also have an id of `username`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `[name="username"]` in your selector, I'll assume that input does not have an ID = "username", which is what you're referencing with `$('#username')`. Without an ID, should be able to reference the current selector using `$(this)`:

```
$('#addNewUserForm input[name="username"]').rules('add', {
    remote: {
        type: 'post',
        url: 'addnewuser/is_username_available',
        data: {
            // referencing the current selector
            'username': function() { return $(this).val(); }         },
        dataType: 'json'
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I add in what I want the custom message to be for this.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules after remote: {...}, just define a messages {...} structure as usual.